# Wait for messages in IMAP Gmail mailbox

Tags: java, networking, email

I used the idle command to wait for incoming messages in my Gmail mailbox. The protocol I am using is IMAP.

My concern is as follows:

While the below code works, Gmail has a tendency to try to interrupt the connection. Therefore, I found some solutions online including sending a periodic NOOP command and catching the `FolderClosedException` exception and handling it by reopening the folder and continue listening idly.

This is what I came up with below and would like any feedback:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.FolderClosedException;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.event.MessageCountEvent;
import javax.mail.event.MessageCountListener;

import com.sun.mail.iap.ProtocolException;
import com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder;
import com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol;



public class ImapReconnect {

    private IMAPFolder imapFolder;
    private IMAPFolder processedFolder;
    private IMAPFolder invalidFolder;
    private static final long KEEP_ALIVE_FREQ = 1000;
    private static final String IRIDIUM_MAILBOX_PROCESSED="Processed";
    private static final String IRIDIUM_MAILBOX_INVALID="Invalid";

    private void startService(){
        try {
            setup();
        } catch( MessagingException e) {
            System.out.println("Error configuring imap server:");
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Thread keepAlive = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                keepAliveRunner();
            }
        });
        keepAlive.start();

        imapFolder.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountListener(){

            public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("New message was added.");
            }

            @Override
            public void messagesRemoved(MessageCountEvent arg0) {

            }

        });

        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            try {
                imapFolder.idle();
            } catch (FolderClosedException e) {
                System.out.println("The remote server closed the IMAP folder, we're going to try reconnecting.");
                startService();
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                System.out.println("Now closing imap mailbox, due to unhandlable exception: ");
                System.out.println(e.toString());
                break;
            }      
        }

        if (keepAlive.isAlive()) {
            keepAlive.interrupt();
        }

        try {
            imapFolder.close(false);
            processedFolder.close(false);
            invalidFolder.close(false);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            System.out.println("Error closing all the folders:");
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    private void setup() throws MessagingException{
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        Store store = session.getStore();

        store.connect("imap.googlemail.com", 993,"myemail@gmail.com","password");
        imapFolder = (IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("INBOX");

        processedFolder = (IMAPFolder) imapFolder.getFolder(IRIDIUM_MAILBOX_PROCESSED);
        if(!processedFolder.exists())
            processedFolder.create(Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES);

        invalidFolder = (IMAPFolder) imapFolder.getFolder(IRIDIUM_MAILBOX_INVALID);
        if(!invalidFolder.exists())
            invalidFolder.create(Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES);

        imapFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
    }

    public void keepAliveRunner(){
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            try {
                // sleep for 5 minutes
                Thread.sleep(KEEP_ALIVE_FREQ);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                imapFolder.doCommand(new IMAPFolder.ProtocolCommand() {
                    public Object doCommand(IMAPProtocol p)
                            throws ProtocolException {
                        p.simpleCommand("NOOP", null);
                        return null;
                    }
                });
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImapReconnect reconnect = new ImapReconnect();
        reconnect.startService();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `com.sum.mail.iap`? Have you verified that this program works?

Comment: @200_success http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.mail/mail/1.4.7/com/sun/mail/iap/ProtocolException.java

Comment: Is addMessageCountListener method scan the gmail server all the time ? if yes then is it efficient memory and computation wise ?

Answer (score 3):

## Threads:

Threads are ***hard.*** It's difficult to do it right and very very easy to mess up. One of the things you shouldn't do are so called *Busy Waits*.
These busy waits is calls to `Thread.sleep()` with values other than \$0\$ or \$1\$. You got one with the value \$1000\$

This is a big code-smell and I already got an idea why you did it that way.

#### Periodically doing stuff

Your design is somewhat off. Usually the checking of mailbox is accomplished a little differently than keeping the IMAP connection open.

Instead you **once** synchronize your folders and then have a scheduler redo that in the background again and again.
The standard way to do this seems to be (*no experience on my side*) to authenticate every request to the SMTP-Server.

You can accomplish this by using [`ScheduledExecutorService` interface.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) There is a method `scheduleAtFixedRate()` provided. I suggest you use that instead of going for `Task`. Your code would then change from:

> ```
>     //... some code
>     Thread keepAlive = new Thread(new Runnable(){
>         public void run() {
>             keepAliveRunner();
>         }
>     });
>     keepAlive.start();
>     //... other code ;)
> }
>
> public void keepAliveRunner(){
>     while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
>         try {
>             // sleep for 5 minutes
>             Thread.sleep(KEEP_ALIVE_FREQ);
>         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>         try {
>             imapFolder.doCommand(new IMAPFolder.ProtocolCommand() {
>                 public Object doCommand(IMAPProtocol p)
>                         throws ProtocolException {
>                     p.simpleCommand("NOOP", null);
>                     return null;
>                 }
>             });
>         } catch (MessagingException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

to:

```
    //... some code
    ScheduledExecutorService keepAlive = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    Runnable toKeepAlive = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            keepAliveRunner();
        }
    };
    keepAlive.scheduleAtFixedRate(toKeepAlive,
          KEEP_ALIVE_FREQ, 
          KEEP_ALIVE_FREQ, 
          TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); 
    /* you could use seconds / minutes instead, but then
    You'd need to change KEEP_ALIVE_FREQ ;) */
    //... other code ;)
}

public void keepAliveRunner() {
   try {
       imapFolder.doCommand(new IMAPFolder.ProtocolCommand() {
           public Object doCommand(IMAPProtocol p)
                   throws ProtocolException {
               p.simpleCommand("NOOP", null);
               return null;
           }
       });
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This should accimplish the same, but doesn't block a whole thread with a busy wait (which isn't nice for your CPU). Also this largely reduces the complexity of your `keepAliveRunner()` method, which I would rename to `runKeepAliveRequest()` now.

**This does not incorporate the changes I suggested earlier. I have no idea how the rest of your code works, so I just leave it like that and hope you can use it ;)**

Comment: Quick question. With this recommended change, what should I do with this:   if (keepAlive.isAlive()) {
      keepAlive.interrupt();
     }

Comment: Should i replace it with keepAlive.shutdown()?

Comment: One final thought if I a may. One of my main concerns was if FolderClosedException is thrown. Is doing a recursive call to startService() to rebound from the exception a workable thing here?

Comment: @JohnMerlino concerning `keepAlive.shutdown()`, Yes, definitely. Concerning `FolderClosedException`: no clue, I don't know the specifics of IMAP and how you handle that. Also that might depend on what exactly you want to accomplish (sorry for the long pipeline)